# comma separated views list

Tags: drupal, view

everyone. I've got a problem with Views 2. I have a view with row's style set to fields (Got only title field). I want to display these titles with comma separated list. 
For example:

Kazakhstan, England, China, Korea

tried to do this:

```
foreach($fields['title']->content as $titles) {

$zagolovki[] = $titles['view'];

}

$title_list = implode(', ', $zagolovki);

print $title_list;
```

but it doesn't works - says error in argument. Please help me someone to display node titles in views with comma separated list. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post more of the code? Is this from a template? I would say `$fields['title']->content` is not an array.

Comment: That's all code in my views-view-fields--related-posts-by-author--block-1.tpl.php template. I am displaying fields with this way.

Answer (score 1):

I quikly took a look in the `views-view-fields.tpl.php` that comes with the views module and it says

```
 /*
 * - $view: The view in use.
 * - $fields: an array of $field objects. Each one contains:
 *   - $field->content: The output of the field.
 *   - $field->raw: The raw data for the field, if it exists. This is NOT output safe.
 *   - $field->class: The safe class id to use.
 *   - $field->handler: The Views field handler object controlling this field. Do not use
 *     var_export to dump this object, as it can't handle the recursion.
 *   - $field->inline: Whether or not the field should be inline.
 *   - $field->inline_html: either div or span based on the above flag.
 *   - $field->separator: an optional separator that may appear before a field.
 * - $row: The raw result object from the query, with all data it fetched.
 */
```

So I think $fields is what you should iterate over. If you want to debug the structure of your `$fields` install the [devel-module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use [dpm()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--devel--devel.module/function/dpm/6) or [dsm()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--devel--devel.module/function/dsm/6) to display the content of `$field`. Maybe take the template you edited (that should be one of the [view-module](http://drupal.org/project/views) templates in the `views/theme` folder) and look what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

Where does it say the error occurs, though? nonsenz is probably right that `$fields['title']->content` is not an array. For debugging only, try adding

```
print("array content: "+ is_array($fields['title']->content));
```

before the foreach. If you know that $fields is a small nested structure, you can try a

```
print(str_replace("\n","<br/>",print_r($fields,true));
```

to see what exactly is in it, so that you can make verify that what you're trying to iterate over is in fact iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this module:

http://drupal.org/project/views_delimited_list

I'm not too sure about fiddling with the options to create merely a comma-separated list. You should be able to, and if you can't I'll fix it.